# Ist es "Ich wohne bei" oder "Ich wohne mit"?

Tags: word-usage

Welcher Satz ist richtig?

1. "Ich wohne bei meinen Eltern."
2. "Ich wohne mit meinen Eltern."

Wenn beide richtig sind, was ist das Unterschied?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Beide Sätze sind richtig, betonen aber jeweils einen anderen Aspekt. Der Satz

> Ich wohne mit meinen Eltern.

drückt einfach nur aus, dass es eine Wohnung gibt, in der meine Eltern und ich zusammen wohnen. Dabei spielt es keine Rolle, wer Mieter oder Eigentümer ist. Das könnten (1) nur meine Eltern sein, (2) meine Eltern und ich gemeinsam, (3) nur ich oder (4) sogar niemand von uns (zum Beispiel wenn ich mit meinen Eltern zusammen im Haus meiner Großeltern wohnte).

In dem Satz

> Ich wohne bei meinen Eltern.

schwingt hingegen mit, dass meine Eltern die Mieter oder Eigentümer der Wohnung sind und ich *bei* ihnen wohne.

---

<sup>**Zusatz zur Verbreitung (unabhängig von der Frage über die Richtigkeit):**


Der Satz</sup>

> <sup>Ich wohne mit meinen Eltern.</sup>

<sup>wird eher selten so verwendet, denn üblicherweise wird noch ein Ort oder eine andere Beifügung angegeben. Zum Beispiel:</sup>

> <sup>Ich wohne mit meinen Eltern *in dem Haus meiner Großeltern.*</sup>
>
> <sup>Ich wohne mit meinen Eltern *zusammen.*</sup>
>
> <sup>Ich wohne mit meinen Eltern *zur Miete.*</sup>

Comment: Das ist ein sehr subtiler Unterschied. Ich verstehe ihn nach einigem Nachdenken und meine, du hast Recht, aber in einem Gespräch würde ich nachfragen – wenn es mich denn interessierte.

Comment: Ich halte diese Auskunft für mehr falsch als richtig. Die idiomatische Verwendung lautet "bei jemandem wohnen"; "mit" wird nur verwendet, wenn auch noch die Lokation genannt wird: "Ich wohne mit meinen Eltern in einer Eigentumswohnung". Man sollte einem Nicht-Muttersprachler nicht weismachen, dass beides gleich verbreitet sei (insbesondere wenn in der Muttersprache tatsächlich "con" oder "with" korrekt wäre).

Comment: Dem kann ich nur zustimmen: Ich würde sagen, dass "mit" ohne Lokation so gut wie nicht gebräuchlich ist. "Bei" ist auf jeden Fall häufiger.

Comment: @KilianFoth Kannst du dich festlegen, daß "mit" nur mit der Lokation richtig ist, du bist da nicht eindeutig? Björn behauptet ja nicht, daß beide gleich verbreitet sind. Es ist durchaus üblich zu sagen "ich wohne mit zusammen" wobei das "zusammen" auch mal gerne weg gelassen wird, was nicht schön klingt, aber ggf. Sprachgebrauch ist.

Comment: @KilianFoth, an keiner Stelle habe ich irgendetwas zur Verbreitung geschrieben. Die Frage war, ob beides _richtig_ ist, nicht ob beides _gleich verbreitet_ ist. Dass der erste Satz selten allein so dasteht, mag zwar stimmen, ändert aber nichts an seiner Richtigkeit. Zudem muss es nicht unbedingt eine Ortsangabe sein, damit er idiomatischer klingt: _"Ich wohne mit meinen Eltern zusammen"_ ist meines Erachtens völlig okay.

Comment: @BjörnFriedrich Vielleicht wäre es möglich, das ein bisschen auszuformulieren, schön klingt es halt wirklich nicht. ;-)

Comment: Vielen Dank, ich habe viel gelernt.