# "Nach" vs "Zu", "Mit" vs "Bei", oder: Die Grenzen von ChatGPT

Tags: preposition

Ich bin dabei, die Präpositionen zu wiederholen, und ich hatte zwei Sätze, von denen das Übungsbuch sagt, dass sie falsch sind:

- A1. Mein Bruder wohnt immer noch bei seinen Schwiegereltern
- A2. Mein Bruder wohnt immer noch mit seinen Schwiegereltern
- B1.  Wenn man von Deutschland nach Norden fährt, kommt man nach Skandinavien.
- B2. Wenn man von Deutschland zum Norden fährt, kommt man zu Skandinavien.

Ich habe A2 und B2 geschrieben, während das Buch meint, dass die Antworten A1 und B1, richtig sind. Ich habe ChatGPT danach gefragt.  Er meinte, dass bei den beiden Satzpaaren, alle Antworten richtig sind.

Schon gut, beim Satzpaar A war ich einverstanden, ich glaubte, dass meine Antwort und die des Buchs richtig sind.  Aber beim Satzpaar B zweifelte ich.  Also habe ich ChatGPT -- in Hinsicht auf Satzpaar B -- folgendes gefragt:

> Bist du sicher, dass der zweite Satz richtig ist?  Kannst du das genau überprüfen?

Darauf hat ChatGPT geantwortet, dass der zweite Satz falsch sei.

Dann habe ich ChatGPT gefragt, nochmals in Hinsicht auf Satzpaar B, ob der zweite Satz *wirklich falsch* war, und er hat dann geantwortet, das der zweite Satz tatsächlich richtig war.

Kurz gesagt hat ChatGPT ständig verschiedene, sich widersprechende Antworten gegeben:

1. Alle Sätze sind richtig
2. Satz B2 ist falsch
3. Satz B2 ist richtig.

(Ich weiß, dass das bei ChapGTP nicht unerwartet ist; trotzdem hatte ich geglaubt, dass ich ihm bei solch "leichten" Fragen vertrauen könne.)

Also habe ich zwei Fragen, wenn Ihr Zeit habt:

- In Hinsicht auf die zwei Satzpaare: Sind meine Sätze richtig oder falsch?
- Kann man in diesem Moment auf ChatGPT bezüglich Grammatikfragen überhaupt vertrauen?  Wenn nicht, und wenn es mehr als eine einzige richtige Antwort gibt, kann man deine Antwort irgendwie überprüfen?  Mit DeepL oder sowas?

Comment: Die erste Frage sind in Wirklichkeit zwei Fragen, die schon hier gestellt und beantwortet wurden: https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/8479/richtungen-und-ziele-wir-fahren-nach-in-zu-an-artikel-xyz und https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/41217/ist-es-ich-wohne-bei-oder-ich-wohne-mit/4121

Comment: @RHa Danke!  Also hatte ich Recht mit A2, und nicht mit B2, wie ich geahnt habe.

Comment: Wenn jemand *immer noch* eine Wohnung mit seinen Eltern teilt, spricht das aus meiner Sicht dafür, dass die Wohnung den Eltern gehört, und dann würde man *bei* benutzen, auch wenn *mit* rein grammatikalisch nicht falsch ist.

Comment: Die Konstruktion mit "mit" wird deshalb angeboten, weil sie ein für Englisch-Sprecher extrem naheliegender und häufiger Fehler ist.

Comment: ChatGPT does not have a notion of correctness. ChatGPT aims to produce answers that sound good.

Comment: @CarstenS und es ist extrem *harmoniebedürftig*: ChatGPT wird fast immer auf Korrekturen vom Benutzer (zumindestens teilweise) eingehen, sogar dann, wenn sie grottenfalsch sind. Ich hätte eigentlich angenommen, dass AI einen Satz von (unverrückbaren) Axiomen kennt. Das scheint aber nicht so zu sein.

Comment: @tofro, das ist das grundsätzliche Missverständnis. Es ist ein Large *Language* Model. Es produziert natürlich wirkenden Text. Und in einer natürlichen Unterhaltung korrigiert man sich oft auf Nachfrage. Übrigens, eine meiner Lieblingsfragen: https://ai.stackexchange.com/q/38270/64952

Comment: Ich hatte gedacht, dass ChatGPT etwas so sehr strukuriert wie Grammtikregeln und ihren Einsatz gut beherrschen würde.  Offensichtlich ist das nicht so.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A1 und A2 sind beide richtig. Man kann sowohl *mit* als auch *bei* jemandem wohnen. Wobei *bei* impliziert, dass die Schwiegereltern Besitzer der Wohnung sind, während *mit* gemeinschaftlichen Besitz transportiert.

Zugegeben, das "immer noch" impliziert allerdings A1 und A1 dürfte auch wesentlich gängiger sein.

B1 ist richtig, B2 falsch. *Nach* kann verwendet werden, wenn man eine allgemeine *Richtung* angibt, während *zu* einen sehr spezifischen Zielpunkt verlangt:

> Ich fahre von Deutschland nach Norden

> Ich fahre von Deutschland zum Nordkapp

Beide Beispiele scheinen so gewählt zu sein, weil sie typische "falsche Freunde" sind und die jeweils falschen Beispiele die direkte Übersetzung der Präposition aus dem Englischen übernehmen ("live *with* someone", "drive *to* the north").

Comment: Mir erscheint B2 auch unvollständig. Nicht im grammatischen Sinn, aber dennoch. Ich würde viel eher „ich wohne mit meinen Eltern in Berlin“ oder „ich wohne mit meinen Eltern“ akzeptieren.

Comment: @CarstenS Du meinst A2? Ich denke, man kann den Satz "Ich wohne mit meinen Schwiegereltern" formulieren, wenn man betonen will, dass es sich um gemeinschaftlichen Besitz handelt (also, wenn man sich ganz klar vom "bei" abgrenzen will). Dafür wäre der Satz auch vollständig genug. Und wenn ich das vor 5 Jahren getan habe und heute immer noch tue, ändert auch das "immer noch" nix an der Gültigkeit. (Wie immer kann man Situationen konstruieren, in denen auch normalerweise "falsche" Sätze gültig sein können)

Comment: Ja, sorry, A2. Ich denke auch, dass der Satz nicht notwendig falsch ist und es auf den Kontext ankommt, wie natürlich er ist. Ich bin mir auch nicht sicher, was es ist, das mich da zumindest ein „zusammen“ einfügen wollen lässt. Und mir ist klar, dass die Tendenz zu diesen eigentlich redundanten Satzteilen regional und persönlich variiert und vielleicht sogar als schlechter Stil gesehen werden kann.

Answer (score 2):

Ich würde keine der Versionen B in der Realität benutzen.
B3: Wenn man AUS Deutschland nach Norden fährt, kommt man nach Skandinavien.